# Sip call with G729 support

Tags: native, sip, codec, android-2.3-gingerbread

I want to support G729 codec for my Sip client(Gingerbread native sip Api), but i have no idea how to do it.
Please provide some links or tutorial to do so.

Comment: Hi all-ok... Did you find a solution for your problem? I'm facing the same problem, and i don't know how to deel with it. Thanks for the time to answer... :)

Comment: I didn't look much for implementing by myself but used cSipSimple to get it working as i supports from 2.1 and has all the codecs required.

Comment: You should also look into imsDroid its a good open source with XMPP implementation.

Comment: CSipSimple looks ok, but it is hard to understand. I don't know how and where to start. What did you do? How did you build it? I appreciate your time... :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that easily. You can't configure the codec you use with the native stack. Also, the native stack supports only a handful of codecs and G.729 isn't one of them.

You may look for another Sip stack with more features like http://www.pjsip.org/.

Comment: Is G729 is configurable with MjSip?

Comment: @Alvi_1987: It would be better if you ask the question directly on SO instead of inside a comment.